# Calendar Incorporation Into Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am working on an application that in the end will have many different users calendars to manage.

The main issue is I don't want to maintain this data I simply want to allow them to create an account my on application then immediately have access to a personal calendar where they can add and create events.  I'm not very familiar with the options out there but is this something I could do with google calendar?  I don't have the users to have to take an extra step to login through google in order to access their personal calendar - which I think it is a requirement to have some type of google account to use a google calendar.

Basically I want a black box.

User creates account on my app - shouldn't have to log into anything external

The user can add events to their calendar -> I send json or something out to this calendar service i.e black box

calendar service receives request and manages

I can then request from calendar service for info -> calendar sends back json or something to me from the black box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Google calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) when the user creates their account on your system you are going to have to request access to their Google calendar account using [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).  When you have done this you should make sure to request off line access so that you have a refresh token giving you access to their account at a later date.    When they add an event to their calendar you can use the refresh token to gain a new access token which will give you access to write to their google calendar.

Comment: when you say request access to their google calendar does this mean they already have registered at google?  I dont want them to have had already registered at google or have to register.

Comment: you say user's calendar they have to have a Google account to have a calendar on Google.    unless you intended to create Google calendars for each of your user's using a service account which I don't think will work as there is probably a limit to the number of calendars you can create

Comment: yeah thats the problem i am trying to find a service that simply maintains these calendars so I don't have to recreate it.   I don't want my users to have to have google accounts or create them.  It seems like I will just have to maintain their calendars in my DB and mange them myself

Comment: check out server account with Google calendar I am not sure if there is a limit to how many you can create